# Atomless and with atoms $\kappa$-additive measures on a cardinal $\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

Is it consistent (with ZFC) that there is a cardinal $\kappa$ and $m_1$ and $m_2$ two measures on $\kappa$, both $\kappa$-additive, such that

1. $m_1$ is atomless, and
2. $m_2$ has an atom?

In that case, the existence of $m_1$ implies that the continuum is at least as large as $\kappa$ and the existence of $m_2$ implies that $\kappa$ is inaccessible. That would mean a radical failure of CH. Of course, we know from Easton's Theorem that the size of the continuum can be "almost" anything. Even then, I am curious to know if $m_1$ and $m_2$ can coexist.

Comment: Real valued measures or $\{0,1\}$-valued ? In any case, I think it's rather $m_1$ that implies that $k$ is inaccessible. And we can't prove that it's consistent with ZFC (unless ZFC isn't) because if we could, then we'd know that an inaccessible is consistent, which would mean ZFC is inconsistent

Comment: m1 is atomless, so must be real-valued. m2 can also be real-valued, but if A is an atom, we can use that to construct a two-valued k additive measure. Agreed, we can't prove its consistency (unless ZFC is inconsistent). My modified question is, "is the coexistence of m1 and m2 provably inconsistent with ZFC". I understand some set theorists hoped that measurable cardinal hypothesis would turn out to be inconsistent with ZFC.

Comment: How does "atomless" imply real-valued ? If $k$ is measurable it has a two valued atomless measure... Also I don't get how an atom allows a nontrivial two valued measure (any principal ultrafilter yields an atomless measure). Such an m2 exists on *any* set, that's what I don't understand

Comment: 1. Let m be a two-valued measure on k and let A be s/t m(A)>0. Then, m(A)=1. For any subset B of A, either m(B)=0, or m(B)=1=m(A). So, A is an atom. So m is not atomless. Thus, "atomless" implies real-valued. 2. Let m be a k-additive non-trivial measure on k with atom A. Define m' on P(k) by m'(x) = m(x intersection A) / m(A). Then m' is a two-valued, k-additive two valued measure on k, as can easily be checked.

Comment: Ok sorry there was a misunderstanding on my part of what you called atom !

Comment: That's ok. It was great conversing with you. I'm 50+ and a management graduate and a law doctorate. Only recently, I developed interest in foundations of mathematics and particularly philosophy of set theory. Since I'm on my own here with noone to discuss things with, this kind of conversations are very helpful.

Comment: Here's something of interest then : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117240/a-measurable-cardinal-a-real-valued-measurable-cardinal-in-the-same-model  (not entirely the same thing but related)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the measures to be $0$ on singletons. If this is the intention, it is impossible for both measures to coexist, for the reason that you identify: $m_1$ would force $\kappa$ to be (atomlessly) real-valued measurable, which implies that $\kappa\le\mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|$, while $m_2$ would force $\kappa$ to be a measurable cardinal, and therefore strictly larger than $\mathfrak c$.

(Of course, if you do not add the requirement that the measures vanish on singletons, then we have a silly example by starting with a real-valued measurable cardinal and a witnessing measure $m_1$, and letting $m_2$ be the $\{0,1\}$-measure corresponding to a principal ultrafilter on $\kappa$.)

---

Kanamori's book on large cardinals and Fremlin's survey on real-valued measurability are both good places to read on this topic. Both discuss in an accessible manner the details required to fully understand the first paragraph above.

Comment: Yes, I'm studying Kanamori's book, At times, his proofs are quite short and cryptic, where I refer to Jech's book. But must a measurable cardinal be strictly bigger than c? I thought by Easton's Theorem, any cardinal with an uncountable cofinality can serve as the value of c.

Comment: Yes, but Easton's theorem does not preserve in general large cardinals. In particular, measurable cardinals are strongly inaccessible, so they are strictly larger than $\mathfrak c $. What Easton's theorem ensures is that if $\kappa $ is measurable, then in a forcing extension $\mathfrak c\ge\kappa $, so in the extension $\mathfrak c $ is large for sure, but $\kappa $, although still regular limit, it is no longer strongly inaccessible.

Comment: A simpler version of the same issue is that if $\omega_1$ is collapsed, then the old $\omega_1$ is now countable. This does not mean that the $\omega_1$ of the extension is countable.

Comment: (And, by the way, the result you are recalling is due to Solovay and precedes Easton's theorem.)

Comment: Ok. So the way I understand it is if we are in the "real" V - the ground model - any "actually" measurable k will always be bigger than the "actual" c. However, we can build a forcing extension V' where the set that V' thinks is c is bigger than the actual k, but at the cost of k losing its measurability w.r.t. V'.

Comment: Exactly. Thinking of it that way is actually useful. For instance, it suggests that if $\mathfrak c$ is real-valued measurable, then there is an inner model where it was (true) measurable. (And this is actually the case.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll think over it. And yes, it was really stupid of me. Since any measurable m is strongly inaccessible, obviously aleph-null - the least infinite cardinal - cannot do one powerset jump and cross (or even hit) m.

Comment: Why does it imply $\kappa \leq \mathfrak{c}$ ?

Comment: @Max Why *what* implies $\kappa\le\mathfrak c$?

Comment: @Max Are you asking why atomless real-valued measurability of $\kappa$ implies that $\kappa\le\mathfrak c$? This is an argument that it may make more sense to ask as a separate question, or to read in either Kanamori's or Jech's book. It is not too difficult, but takes some time to set up. The key point is that if $\mu$ is an atomless measure and $\mu(A)>0$ then there is $B\subset A$ such that $\mu(B)=\mu(A)/2$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I thought it was trivial and I was missing something (seeing how you put it)

Comment: @Andres Thanks for editing the question for notational hygiene. Next time I'll try to be more meticulous.